# Hatcher's explanation on deriving homology group of real projective plane

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

At the page 144 of Hatcher's Algebraic topology, he calculate the boundary map $d_{k} : H_{k+1}(\mathbb{R}P^{k+1},\mathbb{R}P^{k}) \to H_{k}(\mathbb{R}P^{k},\mathbb{R}P^{k-1})$as below;

> To complete the boundary map $d_{k}$, we compute the degree of the composition $S^{k-1} \to \mathbb{R}P^{k-1} \to \mathbb{R}P^{k-1}/\mathbb{R}P^{k-2} = S^{k-1}$, with $\psi: S^{k-1} \to \mathbb{R}P^{k-1}$ is attaching map and $q:\mathbb{R}P^{k-1} \to \mathbb{R}P^{k-1}/\mathbb{R}P^{k-2}$ is quotient map. The map $q\psi$ is a homeomorphism when restricted to each component of $S^{k-1}-S^{k-2}$ and these two homeomorphism are obtained from each other by precomposing with the antipodal map of $S^{k-1}$, which has degree $(-1)^{k}$. Hence
>
> deg$q\psi = $deg $\mathbb{1}$+deg $\mathbb{-1} = 1+(-1)^{k}$.

Actually I have a question on the last equation. Why $q\psi$ restricted on the upper hemisphere is homotopic equivalent to identity? Is there any possibility that $q\psi$ restricted on the upper hemisphere is reflection so that it has degree -1?

Comment: @JohnHughes Can you explain a little bit more? How can I use the ordinary orientation on $S^n$ to derive degree of $q\psi$?

Comment: For most purposes, it doesn't matter whether $q\psi$ on the upper hemisphere has degree $1$ or $-1$; you could just compose your attaching map with a reflection on $S^{k-1}$ to get a different presentation of $\mathbb{R}P^k$ as a CW-complex for which it has the opposite sign.

Comment: @EricWofsey So you mean that even if I compose my attaching map with a reflection on $S^{k-1}$, it gives me deg $p\psi$ = deg(Reflection) + deg(Antipodal of reflection) = $(-1) + (-1)^{k+1}$ so that 0 if $k$ is odd, $-1$ if $k$ is even, hence homology group does not change. I understand. Thanks.